# Glass rendering incorrectly with dark areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

I am a fresh newbie in Blender. I watched lots of tutorials from Blender Guru, and wanted to make a potion bottle. I don't know what went wrong, but the shading went completely wrong, and for some reason the main spehere doesn't reflect anything. If anyone knows why, please help me!

I used a glass material, mixed with diffuse for the bottle.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dark areas are normals facing the wrong direction. Fix these by selecting everything <kbd>A</kbd> in edit mode and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd>.

To fix refraction issues, add a solidify modifier to the mesh. You might have to adjust the thicker part on the top. The glass shader is trying to guess where the glass is solid, so you should use it on closed meshes  only for the refraction to work correctly.

For tinting glass, use a volume shader in the volume material output instead of mixing the surface with a diffuse shader.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try principled shader.  It will be more... correct. With fresnel effect working you might see big reflections on the edges, just as in real world. Plug that straight into surface output and set transmission to 1, roughness to 0. Btw I am not sure if default IOR is correct for glass.

Comment: He is using 2.78, which did not have Principled Shader

Comment: Oh, ok then maybe he should download a newer version, he doesn't lose anything

Comment: Somebody down voted our answers  :(

Comment: I am new to this website, I thought down voting is only necessary if someone's answer is insulting or something, not when someone tries to find a solution and doesn't succeed.

Comment: You may delete the answer to avoid more down votes :)

Comment: This is probably downvoted because while the principled shader might improve the result, the problem can be completely fixed with the current stable version. The down vote is justified in my opinion, because the provided solution is not recommended for most users (who do not want to update to releases labeled as potentially unstable). However it would have been really helpful to explain the reason after downvoting.

Comment: @JanKulczycki People have different definitions of what the down vote means. For me personally, I would down vote something if the answer is either unclear, obviously incorrect, or lacking effort. It's always recommended to comment to clarify the reasoning behind the vote so that the answer can be improved.